# Mockito verify not failing on Callable object

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, callable

I have the following code for a method that performs an action on a Callable parameter:

```
public static <T> T queryWithRetry(Callable<T> query, int maxTries, int retryIntervalInMilliseconds) throws MongoServiceException, InterruptedException {
    int tries = MAX_TRIES;
    while (tries-- > 0) {
      try {
        return query.call();
      } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        LOGGER.debug(String.format("Query timed out. Retrying attempt %d/%d", MAX_TRIES - tries, MAX_TRIES));
        Thread.sleep(RETRY_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        continue;
    }
    throw new RandomException();
  }
```

I am using Mockito to try to validate that the line `query.call()` is attempted exactly `MAX_TRIES` number of times before throwing a `RandomException`. I try to do this with the following test code:

```
public class CallableQueryTest {
  private static final int MAX_TRIES = 3;
  private static final int RETRY_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 100;

  @Mock
  private Callable<Document> mockCallable;

  @Rule
  public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mockCallable = Mockito.mock(Callable.class);
  }

  @Test
  public void testQueryConfigThrowsRandomExceptionOnTimeout() throws Exception {
    Mockito.when(mockCallable.call()).thenThrow(new TimeoutException("timeout"));

    thrown.expect(RandomException.class);    
    Mockito.verify(mockCallable, Mockito.atMost(1)).call();
    MongoQueryUtils.queryWithRetry(mockCallable, MAX_TRIES, RETRY_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
  }
}
```

The Mockito code successfully tests that a `RandomException` is thrown by the method, but improperly says that the test passes.

This test should fail because I write that Mockito should verify that `mockCallable.call()` is performed at most once, but as far as I understand, it is called `MAX_TRIES` times (which is set to 3).

Could someone explain this behavior and give advice on how to properly test the number of times `mockCallable.call()` is invoked?

Comment: Unrelated: I find the fact that you use all uppercase for the **method parameters** that `queryWithRetry()` declares to confusing. You use all upppercase for CONSTANTS - but the whole idea of that parameter given to the method is: it might be different **each** time it is called. That is just a normal parameter. Beyond that: when you are using Java8, simply do **not** say "this value is coming in milliseconds" by its **name** - use the new Duration classes to simply pass something that can be turned to milliseconds!

Comment: But these variables aren't declared in the method `queryWithRetry()`? They are uppercase because they're constants, defined at the top of the class. They're used throughout the testing file, but I only sampled the first test case in my code. The Duration tip is helpful, thanks!

Comment: The signature of `queryWithRetry()` is (in my eyes) close to unreadable. I know that some folks like putting final everywhere, but I dont find it helpful for method parameters. And as said: it is fine to invoke foo(BAR_CONST), but the method signature should **not** read `void foo(Bar BAR_CONST)` - because you have no idea how the method is invoked. Uppercase is for constants, parameters aren't constants. All imho.

Comment: I guess that is part of the confusion: MAX_TRIES *within* that method is pointing to that method parameter; *not* to that constant. If both things would be in the same file, the local MAX_TRIES would even *shadow* the outer constant. And shadowing is something to be extremely cautious about!

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I didn't originally understand you because I had already updated my local code to reflect this (and forgot to edit the stack overflow)! I reasoned the same way that you did :)

Comment: Glad to hear that ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are **plenty** of things wrong with your test. Here is something that does what you want:

```
private static final int MAX_TRIES = 3;
private static final int RETRY_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 100;

@Mock
private Callable<String> mockCallable;

@Test
public void testQueryConfigThrowsRandomExceptionOnTimeout() throws Exception {
    when(mockCallable.call()).thenThrow(new IllegalArgumentException("timeout"));
    try {
        queryWithRetry(mockCallable, MAX_TRIES, RETRY_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        fail("should have thrown");
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        // as expected
    }
    verify(mockCallable, Mockito.times(3)).call();
}
```

(please note: I changed the exception types for my test; but that should be obvious).

So, things you got wrong:

- I suggest to use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`, and then just go with @Mock annotations. You have the @Mock annotation **plus** a setup method that calls Mockito.mock() for the same field. That is redundant. Either use the annotation together with @RunWith, or call MockitoAnnotations.initMocks() in your setup method
- `verify()` has to be called **after** you interacted with your mock object. Just think of that mock having counters. Before you interact, the counters are all 0. So there is no point asking a mock about its counters **before** you trigger the calls to the mock.
- I am not familiar with JUnit rules; therefore I rewrote the test to work without it. If you want to use the JUnit rule for exception handling; well left to the reader as exercise.

Comment: This ended up working for me, thank you. I did use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`, but forgot to include it in my code sample. One more question: why can't I just move the `verify()` call in my code sample to below the `queryWithRetry()` method? I don't understand why that would not work.

Comment: Because that call throws an exception that needs to be caught in order to continue with the verify call!

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought `thrown.expect(RandomException.class);` would've caught the exception, but I see now that it just detects the exception instead.

Comment: You are welcome. For the record - is there something I can do to make my answer upvote worthy? And in case you just forgot - feel free to do that tomorrow as I already hit the daily cap limit today.